# EmguCV Rotation Algorithm not working

Tags: c#, algorithm, opencv, rotation, emgucv

I want to rotate an image using OpenCV/EmguCV. I've found a rotation algorithm that I want to implement, but the outcome is not quite as I want it to be. Maybe someone can have a look.

My Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mat image = CvInvoke.Imread("C:\\Users\\Leon\\Downloads\\a.jpg", LoadImageType.Grayscale);

        int height = image.Height;
        int width = image.Width;

        //Convert to Matrix
        Matrix<Byte> matrix = new Matrix<Byte>(image.Rows, image.Cols, image.NumberOfChannels);
        image.CopyTo(matrix);

        Matrix<Byte> newMatrix = new Matrix<Byte>(image.Rows, image.Cols, image.NumberOfChannels);
        image.CopyTo(newMatrix);

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Rows - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.Cols - 1; j++)
            {
                newMatrix.Data[i, j] = matrix.Data[(byte)(i * Math.Cos(3) - j * Math.Sin(3)), (byte)(i * Math.Sin(3) + j * Math.Cos(3))];
            }
        }

        CvInvoke.Imshow("abc", newMatrix);
        CvInvoke.WaitKey(0);

    }
}
```

Original Picture:

[image: Vladimir Putin]

My Outcome:

[image: incorrectly rotated]

If someone can point out what I'm doing wrong, I'd be very thankful! :)

Comment: Cant you use Transpose method?

Comment: It's an exercise that I have to do for a course at my University, so I have to implement an algorithm from scratch and I'm not allowed to use built-in functions/methods.

Comment: In color picture every pixel consists of 3 bytes R,G,B. You are ignoring this fact.

Comment: @MBo - That's not totally true, because in Line 3 (LoadImageType.Grayscale) i load the Picture as an Grayscale Image, meaning that it is converted to Grayscale immediately.

Comment: Did you check image.NumberOfChannels ?

Comment: Just checked it. When I write "image.NumberOfChannels" to the console, the output is "1".

Comment: OK. What `(byte)(xxx)` does when xxx is >= 256?

Comment: By way of a simple check, I'd be inclined to replace the inner loop body with `newMatrix.Data[i, j] = matrix.Data[i, j];` and check what I get.

Comment: @MBo - I don't really know how to trigger that, but it would probably give me an "Out of bound" - exeption.

Comment: @AakashM - When I do what you suggest, the output corresponds to the original image.

Answer (score 1):

Pattern with square length 256 says that some coordinate overflow exists.

Look at the casting to byte here:

```
 matrix.Data[(byte)(i * Math.Cos(3) - j * Math.Sin(3)), (byte)(i * Math.Sin(3) + j * Math.Cos(3))];
```

Seems you need to round float values to int, then check - if it lies in range `0..width-1` or `0..height-1` for x and y.

possible pseudocode:

```
cs = Math.Cos(angle); //calculate them once before cycle
sn = Math.Sin(angle);
...
x = (int) (i * cs - j * sn);
y = (int) (i * sn + j * cs);
if (x>=0)&&(x<width)&&(y>=0)&&(y<height)
   {copy byte to new picture}
```

Aside question: what is `3` argument of Sin and Cos?

Comment: I'm really not that good of a coder, so I don't relly know what you mean by what you are suggesting.

Comment: I'm casting to byte, because I get an error if I dont. And the arguments inside Cos and Sin, meaning 3, should represent the angle by what the image is being rotated.

Comment: Argument of trig. function should be in radians, not in degrees. Is 3 radians - what you wanted?

Comment: I wrote this inside the nested for-loop:

                    double angle = 3;
                    double cs = Math.Cos(angle);
                    double sn = Math.Sin(angle);

                    int x = (int)(i * cs - j * sn);
                    int y = (int)(i * sn + j * cs);

                    if ((x >= 0) && (x < width) && (y >= 0) && (y < height))
                    {
                        newMatrix.Data[i, j] = matrix.Data[x, y];
                    }  


But as output I get the same picture as the input image.

Comment: In this case i,j should be equal to x,y?

Comment: I really don't know what I'm doing wrong anymore....
I always get the error "System.IndexOutOfRangeException".
I think that due to either 'X' or 'Y' being a negative number.

Comment: I tried your "if" - statement, but it just outputs me the original image.

Comment: Set angle to Pi/4 and debug, check (i,j) vs (x,y) values. Do you use `width =image.Cols, height=image.Rows`?

Comment: I debuged with PI/4. If I use the suggested for-loop, the output will be the same as the input image. When I use my {copy int to new picture} - code, it will give me an error because it will return a negative number at some point.

Comment: I use matrix and newMatrix.Cols/Rows.